# Can't Access Custom Response Headers with Cordova iOS 6+ WKWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, response-headers

I'm having trouble migrating my cordova app to iOS 6+ with WKWebView.

I've read as much as I can...

I can see the request completing, the developer tools show the response header I'm trying to read, but the XHR result object doesn't contain that response header.  I have set:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

I have the file-xhr plugin install.  I have tried multiple plugins and none will allow me to access my response header.  The result is always limited to the following:

cache-control,content-length,content-type,expires,pragma.

I feel like I must be missing a setting/preference somewhere.  My API passes a number of details through custom headers.  If I can't read them, it will be a major headache.